# SharePoint content type : deleting columns from the parent

Tags: sharepoint, wss-3.0

I'm trying to create a content type that will inherit from the Contact content type (that comes with SharePoint).
I need most of the fields in there but would like to be able to remove some of them.

Is there a way I can remove the fields I don't want through the XML definition of the Content Type?

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ContentType ID="0x01004B56BB872BFE984D9611B5D8CF52CB60" Name="Child Contact" Description="Inherits from Contact" Group="...">
    <FieldRefs>
    ??? What would I put there to remove fields that exist in the parent?
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this syntax in your content type definition:

```
<FieldRefs>
      <RemoveFieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name ="Title"  />
</FieldRefs>
```

You must find proper ID for each filed you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Just hide them in child content type by setting HIDDEN="TRUE" attribute.
See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543225.aspx) for full list of attributes.

Comment: Thanks, very useful list of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need those fields then why are you inheriting from that content type in the first place?

Comment: I need some fields, but not all of them. I inherit from the Contact contact type which has the fields "Phonetic First Name" and "Phonetic Last Name" that I want to get rid of... The rest of the fields are OK.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you rethink your content type inheritance structure then. Define a parent ct that contains JUST the columns shared by both child ct's, and add the other columns to the respective child ct.

Think of it as OO programming, you would not put methods that are used ONLY in subclass B that inherits from class A TO that parent class A, and in the process make that method available in all classes inheriting from A, while they will never be used there, or even worse, be misused...